# add specific characters before and after every cell value

Tags: excel

I have a excel sheet with a bunch of text all in a single column with roughly 5K rows. I need to add the quotes " before and after each of these cell values and also add a comma at the end after the quote too. How can I archieve this using Excel?

### Current State

### somerandomstringvalues

### somerandomstringvalues

### somerandomstringvalues

### Desired Output

### "somerandomstringvalues",

### "somerandomstringvalues",

### "somerandomstringvalues",

Comment: `=CONCAT("""",A1,""",")`

Answer (score 0):

two suggestions:

1: Add a column with the formula

```
=""""&A1&""","
```

Copy the column and paste as values

2: load the data into Power Query, add a column with the formula, delete the original column and load.

The benefit of the second method is that you can repeat it with one mouse click to refresh the query when your data has changed.

Using a function like Concat() or Concatenate is not required. The `&` sign does the job with much less typing in your scenario.

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.